# Cannot read a large FITS file using Astropy.io.fits

Tags: python, out-of-memory, fits, astropy, pyfits

I am currently attempting to read data from a large data FITS format data file using astropy.io.fits for Python 3.4.  While I can successfully open the file using the memmapper mode, I cannot access the data within the file.  Here is my code

```
from astropy.io import fits

hdu_list = fits.open('large_file.fit', memmapper=True)
table = hdu_list[1].data
```

On the second line `table = hdu_list[1].data` I then get `OSError: [WinError 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command`

My thinking is that when assigning the data to the variable `table`, the attempt is made to read the entire file, causing the storage error.  Is there any work around, or a method to simply read in each line of the table data at a time?

Comment: I think you mean `memmap=True`--there is no "memmapper" option.

Comment: Could you post just the header of the FITS file?  That usually contains all the most useful information for debugging issues like this.  Am I correct to guess you're on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Discovered what went wrong.  I tried to open the FITS file with fitsio and then read row by row.  However the program ran for awhile, then threw an IOError.  I found that one of the rows of the file was corrupted, and that was what was causing the inability of astropy.io.fits to read the file without throwing an error.  I am unsure of exactly how the row became corrupted, or exactly what was wrong with it, I simply downloaded a second copy of the FITS file and that fixed the problem.